# C# Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol wrapping default HTTP Protocol throws InvalidCastException

Tags: c#, .net, internet-explorer, http, com

In order to be able to filter URLs fetched (including JS, images, etc.) with the C# web browser (WinForms), the only containable option seems to be a Asynchronous Pluggable Protocol wrapping HTTP (and later on others as well). Unfortunately this fails with an `InvalidCastException` thrown by the original original protocol implementation **after several calls** <- this is also the weird part, it seems to succeed several times before failing.

Now some code:

Firstly the factory for the protocol is registered and attached:

```
  var ep = new FilteredHttpProtocolFactory();
  Guid id = Guid.Parse ("E00957BD-D0E1-4eb9-A025-7743FDC8B27B");
  session.RegisterNameSpace (ep, ref id, "http", 0, null, 0);
```

(The factory:)

```
[Guid ("EF474615-8079-4CFA-B114-6D1D28634DD8")]
[ComVisible (true)]
[ClassInterface (ClassInterfaceType.None)]
public class FilteredHttpProtocolFactory : IClassFactory
{
  public void CreateInstance (object pUnkOuter, Guid riid, out object ppvObject)
  {
    ppvObject = new FilteredHttpProtocol();
  }

  public void LockServer (bool fLock)
  {
  }
}
```

This is the original HTTP protocol used by IE, when using it instead of the wrapper it works just fine:

```
[ComImport]
[Guid ("79eac9e2-baf9-11ce-8c82-00aa004ba90b")]
public class OriginalHttpHandler
{
}
```

This is the wrapper itself:

```
[Guid ("E00957BD-D0E1-4eb9-A025-7743FDC8B27B")]
[ComVisible (true)]
[ClassInterface (ClassInterfaceType.None)]
[AsyncProtocol (Name = "http2", Description = "blah")]
public class FilteredHttpProtocol : IInternetProtocol, IInternetProtocolRoot
{ 
private readonly IInternetProtocol _wrapped;

public FilteredHttpProtocol ()
{
  var originalHttpHandler = new OriginalHttpHandler();
  _wrapped = (IInternetProtocol) originalHttpHandler;
}

public void Start (string szURL, IInternetProtocolSink Sink, IInternetBindInfo pOIBindInfo, uint grfPI, uint dwReserved)
{
  _wrapped.Start (szURL, Sink, pOIBindInfo, grfPI, dwReserved);
}

public void Continue (ref _tagPROTOCOLDATA pProtocolData)
{
  _wrapped.Continue (ref pProtocolData);      // <- FAILS HERE
}
   // .... other methods from IInternetProtocol
    public uint Read (IntPtr pv, uint cb, out uint pcbRead)
    {
      return _wrapped.Read (pv, cb, out pcbRead); // <- OR HERE
    }
}
```

So, the weird part is, that the constructor is called, `Start()` is called, even `Read()` and `Continue()` is called several times until the whole thing fails (either with `Read()` or `Continue()`) when parts of the page are already visible (!), but it seems that mostly one specific image is missing (mostly!) :

```
Unable to cast COM object of type 'Clients.Windows.Protocol.OriginalHttpHandler' 
to interface type 'Clients.Windows.Protocol.IInternetProtocol'. This operation 
failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface 
with IID '{79EAC9E4-BAF9-11CE-8C82-00AA004BA90B}' failed due to the following 
error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 E_NOINTERFACE)).
```

Seeing that I already cast the object to said interface several times (which should result in a `QueryInterface()` call every time, and that it has been called (verified through breakpoints and such) several times before it fails this error is really puzzling. By looking at the ref counts I already ruled out the object being disposed too early (wouldn't make sense anyway).

I have tried several things:

- Google but APPs are fairly rare
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa767916(v=vs.85).aspx
- Inheriting the ComImport'ed object - then my implementation gets ignored
- Look at the ref counts
- Casts of all sorts
- Check GUIDs and interfaces for mistakes
- Asking colleagues

Basically what I am trying to achieve is to wrap the default http protocol implementation of the IE to filter out URLs, including those where resources are retrieved from. I would also be satisfied with suitable alternatives, but they have to be compliant with GPLv2, deployable with the browser application, and do NO changes to rest of the system (i.e. no proxies).

Thanks for your help ;)

btw, this is going to be part of my Master's Thesis here: http://desktopgap.codeplex.com

Comment: Why do you have ClassInterfaceType None? I'd remove it. Also, E_NOINTERFACE can be a threading issue. When is your object created? On what thread? What's this thread apartment type? (http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2004/12/13/281910.aspx)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. 
Indeed after looking into the threads used to call the methods: 

`#1 threadID: 3 C'tor()
#1 URL:  http://...
#1 original thread: 3 calling thread 3 Start() STA
#2 threadID: 3 C'tor()
#2 URL:  http://...
#2 original thread: 3 calling thread 3 Start() STA
#1 original thread: 3 calling thread 14 Continue() MTA
#2 original thread: 3 calling thread 13 Continue() MTA
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException'...
`
However these threads are created by whoever calls them, which is why I am not sure how I could change the apartment...

Comment: Do you create each FilteredHttpProtocol instance on the current thread or do you share the instance?

Comment: ... furthermore it seems that MTA is entered upon requiring more than one subrequest, which in my case are 2 images (objects #1 & #2) to be loaded -- but still each of them has its own object and the same thread is used for their construction.

Comment: My findings look the same as the one's from user2371720's [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16491864/1310241) below, actually. So they seem to be created individually on individual threads as well

Comment: "The same thread is used for their construction"? So you share the instances?

Comment: Two out of the three objects do, yes. the first one - using its own thread for creation - being the request for the page itself; the subsequent ones are two images - created from the same thread but Read() or Continue() with different threads, which seems to cause the error

Comment: I suggest when you create a COM object on a given thread, you only call its method on that same thread. Although it can work on different threads theoretically, some COM server don't like it.

Comment: Yes I also think that this would be the proper way of doing it, however, the methods are called from within mshtml.dll to deal with a URL - I have no influence on the thread and object creation there.

Comment: Even if it's called from a thread you don't own, you shouldn't share COM instances across different threads. It's your responsibility to ensure that, you're the one creating OriginalHttpHandler instances in a specific thread, so you need ensure this instance is not used in other thread.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a day of experimenting COM and reading all sorts of things on the Internet I found the solution.

As [Simon Mourier](https://stackoverflow.com/users/403671/simon-mourier) pointed out it was a threading issue: The `FilteredHttpProtocol` I created supports STA and MTA with COM (= C# default behavior), which the default Http Protocol object doesn't and upon calling a method from a different thread (which apparently happens), the Marshaling fails (also pointed out [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andreww/archive/2008/08/11/why-your-comaddin-object-should-derive-from-standardolemarshalobject.aspx)) throwing E_NOINTERFACE.

Since changing the COM threading behavior is apparently a bit odd (it requires writing to the registry) and did not work for me, the solution was to create a custom STA thread **in the class factory (i.e. the same thread is passed into every FilteredHttpProtocol object)** (rather than the Protocol class itself) and call *every* method using `Invoke()`.

A quick and dirty solution is:

```
[ComVisible (true)]
public class FilteredHttpProtocolFactory : IClassFactory
{
    private readonly Control _ctrl;

    public FilteredHttpProtocolFactory ()
    {
      _ctrl = new Control();
    }

    public void CreateInstance (object pUnkOuter, Guid riid, out object ppvObject)
    {
      ppvObject = new FilteredHttpProtocol(_ctrl);
    }

    public void LockServer (bool fLock)
    {
    }
}
```

And the protocol class itself:

```
[ComVisible (true)]
[AsyncProtocol (Name = "http2", Description = "blah")]
public class FilteredHttpProtocol :  IInternetProtocol, IInternetProtocolRoot
{
    private IInternetProtocol _wrapped;
    private static int s_id = 0;
    private int _id = -1;
    private int _creatingTID = -1;

    private Control _dispatcher;

    public FilteredHttpProtocol (Control ctrl)
    {
      _dispatcher = ctrl;
      _id = s_id;
      s_id++;
      _creatingTID = Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
      Debug.WriteLine ("#" + _id + " threadID: " + _creatingTID + " C'tor()");

      _dispatcher.Dispatcher.Invoke (
          () =>
          {
            var originalHttpHandler = new OriginalHttpHandler();
            _wrapped = (IInternetProtocol) originalHttpHandler;
          });
    }

    public void Start (string szURL, IInternetProtocolSink Sink, IInternetBindInfo pOIBindInfo, uint grfPI, uint dwReserved)
    {
      Debug.WriteLine ("#" + _id + " URL: " + "\t" + szURL);
      _dispatcher.Dispatcher.Invoke (
          () =>
          {
            Debug.WriteLine (
                "#" + _id + " original thread: " + _creatingTID + " calling thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId
                + " Start() "
                + Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState());
            _wrapped.Start (szURL, Sink, pOIBindInfo, grfPI, dwReserved);
          });
    }

    public void Continue (ref _tagPROTOCOLDATA pProtocolData)
    {
      var _pProtocolData = pProtocolData;
      _dispatcher.Dispatcher.Invoke (
          () =>
          {
            Debug.WriteLine (
                "#" + _id + " original thread: " + _creatingTID + " calling thread " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId + " Continue() "
                + Thread.CurrentThread.GetApartmentState());
            _wrapped.Continue (ref _pProtocolData);
          });
      pProtocolData = _pProtocolData;
    }
    // ...
}
```

(please do not use this code as it is ;) )
Thanks for your help, I hope this also helps someone else too.

Cheers,

Claus

Answer (score 0):

Currently I'm investigating the same behavior.

I have two ideas. First is that object is called from another thread it is created:

```
Method, Apartment, ThreadId, ObjId
--------------------
Constructor: , STA, 9, #1
Start: , STA, 9, #1
Continue: , STA, 9, #1
Read: , STA, 9, #1
Read: , STA, 9, #1
Lock: , STA, 9, #1
Read: , STA, 9, #1
Read: , STA, 9, #1
Constructor: , STA, 10, #2
Start: , STA, 10, #2
Constructor: , STA, 10, #3   <-- Notice ThreadId is 10
Terminate: , STA, 9, #1
Start: , STA, 10, #3         <-- Valid call
Constructor: , STA, 10, #4
Start: , STA, 10, #4
Read: , STA, 10, #4
Continue: , MTA, 11, #2
Terminate: , STA, 10, #4
Continue: , MTA, 12, #3      <-- EXCEPTION HERE!!! We have new thread with Id of 12 and MTA apartment
Constructor: , STA, 10, #5
Start: , STA, 10, #5
Constructor: , STA, 10, #6
Unlock: , STA, 9, #1
Start: , STA, 10, #6
```

Second thought that CLR handles COM calls differently than in native c++. I've faced this when tried to utilize DirectShow. So in case of c++ it just takes the pointer to interface and invokes function via v-table. But in case of managed code it queries for interface first. And that additional query interface call could fail or return wrong object if not properly implemented. The solution will be to create native IUknown wrapper which will return pointer to IInternetProtocol on QueryInterface.

Comment: As far as I found out by now, threading - i.e. the object being run in an MTA - is the root cause. The original HTTPProtocol runs in a STA hence the wrapper has to be in one too, but default behavior of a ComVisible object is STA & MTA, thus the invocation from a different thread at some point.